# What is the process to get Script for third party creative Setup in DFP?

Tags: javascript, google-dfp

I a bit confused. I am new to DFP for Small business, yet to complete my first ad setup. I setup adunit, line item and when I tried to add creative (eg. Chitika or any other third party advertiser ), I click on third party.

My question is from where I can get javascript code for third party advertiser. Do I need to contact them via email to get script or is there a weblink to fetch javascript for third party advertisers to be inserted during creatives setup?

If you know the way to contact advertisers for getting third party script for creatives, please tell me the steps. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer and successfully implemented it.

I approached the third party through its website, became member and get the script code. This script code is the same which can also be put into your website/blog directly. I just pasted the script. DFP recognizes automatically and validates whether it is proper or not and then I inserted DFP macros and get it done.

Then I go to generate tag and paste the same tag in my website and the third party ad is showing up.